# Any way of enabling flash on a site without changing the Central Administration

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I want to run my flash code on my site without changing central administration settings. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can embed the flash object, without having to go through Central Administration. Take a look at how to [embed flash with SharePoint Designer](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2012/12/06/how-to-embed-html-code-in-site-sharepoint-designer-2013.aspx).

[image]